# Read a file from the another location using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Here is my code to read a file from the another location using JSch

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SftpClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        FileReader reader =null;
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        try 
        {
.
            session = jsch.getSession("userName", "Ip Address");
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);  
            session.setPassword("password");                
            session.connect();              
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            System.out.println("Is connected to IP:"+channel.isConnected());
            Vector ls=sftpChannel.ls("/misc/downloads/");
            for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
               System.out.println("Ls:"+ls.get(i));
            }
            sftpChannel.cd("/misc/downloads/");             
            File file = new File("Text.txt");
            sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(file),"Text.txt");              
            reader = new FileReader(file);
            buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);                
            String getLine = "";
            while ((getLine = buffer.readLine())!=null)
            {
               System.out.println("Line: "+getLine);
            }
            sftpChannel.exit();             
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally{
            try{
               if(reader!=null)
                  reader.close();
               if(buffer!=null)
                  buffer.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Output of the code is :

```
Is connected to IP:true
Ls:-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          733 Jul 19 17:46 Text.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Text.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
    at SftpClient.main(SftpClient.java:34)
```

I am getting the FileNotFoundException, but before that I made SOP to list all the files in the /misc/downloads/ path using ls.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileInputStream` tries to read the file from your **local** file system (where it does not exist), while it seems that you actually want to read it from the remote file system. Or do you want to download it to the local system and then read from there?

Anyway, to download from the remote side, use one of the `get` methods from [`ChannelSftp`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html), not `put` (which is for uploading).

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) for reading remote files. It'simple and powerful lib.