# How i can read file from unix server after doing some grep operation using java(Jsch)

Tags: java, unix, jsch

I have a text file on server with a size of 200 mb.I want reduce the file content using command (grep keyword1 filename.txt|grep -v keyword2) and then read that file in java using Jsch connection.

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747993/read-a-file-from-the-another-location-using-jsch

Comment: 1) Ask proper questions does help a lot. 2) At which point in your code do you have a problem? Show the related code and the polite people at SO will help to solve your issue. Without seeing your code there is not so much where we could help.

Comment: You might start from here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html. If you have a concrete problem, mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by below code:-

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
try {
  String command="grep 'keyword1' filename.txt|grep -v 'keyword2'";
  session = jsch.getSession(userid, servername, serverport);
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
  session.connect();

  Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
  ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
  channel.connect();

  InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(commandOutput));    
  String line="";                           
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
 {
        System.out.println(line);                               
 }
  br.close();
  channel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```